# How to style the text out side of a div?

Tags: javascript, nodes

I have an auto-generated title that comes from the system. Here's what the HTML look like:

```js
  $("#foo2").contents().filter(function(){ 
       return this.nodeType == 3;         
   })[0].nodeValue = "" ;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Auto-generated text
       <div id="container"></div>
       <div id="menu"></div>
       <ul >
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
       </ul>
```

I was able to select the text and remove it (see my JS) But now I want to style it via jQuery or JS. Does anyone know how to style it? Or how to append it to the `div#container` so I can style it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.appendTo( target )`](https://api.jquery.com/appendTo) to move the text node(s) into `#container`

> **Description**: *Insert every element in the set of matched elements to the end of the
>   target.*
>
> **`target`**
>   Type: [Selector](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Selector) or [htmlString](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#htmlString) or
>   [Element](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element) or
>   [Array](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Array) or
>   [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery)   A selector, element,
>   HTML string, array of elements, or jQuery object; the matched set of
>   elements will be inserted at the end of the element(s) specified by
>   this parameter.

```js
 $("#foo2").contents().filter(function(){ 
    return this.nodeType == 3;
 }).appendTo("#container");
```

```css
#container { color: red }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo2"> Auto-generated text
   <div id="container"></div>
   <div id="menu"></div>
   <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>item 3</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```